# How to configure locally installed hive to use Azure Datalake as warehouse?

Tags: hive, azure-data-lake

I have installed Hive in my local windows system, I have configured it to use MySQL as metastore and I need to configure it to use Azure Data lake as warehouse.
How to configure hive to use Azure Datalake as warehouse?.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but you have to configure your local hadoop system accordingly. 
Ensure that you have the latest ADLS libs and modify the cores-site.xml to access the Azure Data Lake Store:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
        <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
        <value>ClientCredential</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
      <value>YOUR TOKEN ENDPOINT</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id</name>
      <value>YOUR CLIENT ID</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>dfs.adls.oauth2.credential</name>
      <value>YOUR CLIENT SECRET</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>fs.adl.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.adl.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.Adl</value>
  </property>  
</configuration>
```

A step by step guide can be found [here](https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4).

Finally ensure that in the hive-site.xml your "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" points to the ADL.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported use case of Azure Data Lake.  Azure Data Lake is a cloud based data lake and currently supports HDInsight, Azure Data Lake Analytics, or Azure Databricks as its compute engines.  It cannot connect with a locally run instance of Hive.